# Rendering rails partials in the callback function of a Pusher event.

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, unobtrusive-javascript

I am working a fairly simple Rails app where people can ask questions and upvote questions. I want to build in some realtime functionality and decided to go with Pusher to do so (mainly because it seems very compatible with deploying on heroku).

Currently when you add a new question, the following bit of javascript gets executed:

```
if $('.question').hasClass('no_current_questions_notice')  
  $('.no_current_questions_notice').fadeOut 400, ->     
    $(this).replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'questions/added_question', :question => @added_question) %>')
    $('.last_question').hide().fadeIn 400

else
  $('.last_question').removeClass('last_question')  
  $('#added_question').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'questions/added_question', :question => @added_question) %>')
  $('.last_question').hide().fadeIn 400
```

I was hoping that I could simply reuse my partial in the Pusher callback so I could recreate what happens after an AJAX request for a pusher event. See below in simplest form:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var pusher = new Pusher('<%= Pusher.key %>');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('course-<%= @course.id %>');
channel.bind('create_question', function(data) {
  var @added_question = data;
  $('#added_question').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'questions/added_question', :question => @added_question) %>');
  });
</script>
```

and for reference this is my partial:

```
<div class='question last_question'>
    <div class='question_content'>  
        <%= question.content %>
    </div>  
    <%= render 'upvotes/agree', :question => question %>
</div>
<div id='added_question'>
</div>
```

Ok. So my this throws up the error 'undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass' right when I try to load the page. This makes sense because question isn't defined until there is a 'create-question' event. However, I don't understand why Rails is trying to render that partial before the 'create-question' event. (BTW I checked and without the partial, everything else works and the data gets sent through from Pusher).

Most other examples of pusher integration I found had fairly heavy client-side javascript. As I am no javascript wizard, I was hoping that I don't have to redo the front-end of my app just to incorporate pusher. Is there a way to keep my code DRY and use my partials in a Pusher callback?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more research I think I have found a solution for now. This gist helped me send the fully rendered partial through Pusher: https://gist.github.com/1154209.

This method works for me as it allows me to reuse my partials and incorporate Pusher. I went for option 3 in the Gist because it would allow you to add more data to be sent through in the future relatively easily.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in Rails 4 - do you have any updated code?